# How can I find the length of 12 gauge wire needed for a cone of if I know it's surface area

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical

So I'm working on a personal project, and I need to figure out how much 12 gauge wire (which is ~2mm thick) I would need to cover a cone shaped rubber core, which has a surface area of roughly 3,417,810 mm^2. I have no idea where to start with figuring it out and would appreciate the help!

Comment: If you already know the surface area, does it still matter what the geometry is? Area = length x width, you already have the area (3.4E6 mm^2), and width (~2 mm), your length should be 1,708,905 mm. This seems like an awfully long wire...

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but no one I asked here seemed to know what I was even taking about. And yeah, the rubber cone is ~59" high and ~21" radius - but only in the 3d modeling software. I didn't like the camera controls so I made it bigger than my original plans by a multiple of 10 for ease of access

Comment: So increasing length by a factor of 10 increases area by a factor of 100, meaning you'd need 17,089 mm approximate length. That seems more reasonable, but still a lot of wire. What are you making?

Comment: Uh maybe potentially possibly toying with the idea of potentially making an engine that uses electromagnetism? I won't be able to prototype it until I get some funding of course (and a 3d printer) but it doesn't hurt to design beforehand.

Comment: You might save yourself a lot of work and gain some insight if you discuss your idea with someone who understands electromagnetism. Your question and comments suggest that you may have some misconceptions about how stuff works.